# Is it method overriding or overloading?

Tags: java, overloading, overriding

```
public class Tester {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      A a2 = new B();
      a2.dosomething1(new B());
      a2.dosomething2(new B());
   }
}

class A {
   public void dosomething1(A a){
      System.out.println("Inside a  dosomething1");
   }

   public void dosomething2(A a){
      System.out.println("Inside a  dosomething2");
   }
}

class B extends A {
   public void dosomething1(A a){
      System.out.println("Inside b dosomething1");
   }

   public void dosomething2(B b){
      System.out.println("Inside b  dosomething2");
   }
}
```

Output

```
Inside b dosomething1
Inside a  dosomething2
```

The first line in output is clearly due to method overriding. 
But what is the reason behind second line ?  Why java not calling the method defined in B as on runtime it knows a2 is object of B.

Comment: _Polymorphism_. One word, a thousand implications.

Comment: probably because `dosomething2` signature doesn't match parent's signature, yes java allows overrides to specify a subclass as return type but apparently not as parameter type

Comment: Did you search before asking? Similar questions have been asked and answered many times.

Comment: @OleV.V. yes.  But I wanted answer precisely for this this scenario. rather confirm my understanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question you need to answer is this: can `B.dosomething2(B b)` fully replace `A.dosomething2(A a)`? Or more specifically: can every parameter value accepted by `A.dosomething2(A a)` also be passed to `B.dosomething2(B b)`?

The answer is simple: no.

```
B obj_B= new B();
A obj_A= new A();
obj_B.doSomething2(obj_A);
```

The example above should make it clear why: `obj_A` is not an instance of `B`, so it can't be passed as a parameter to `B.dosomething2(B b)`. Which means that the two methods, although they share the same name do not share the same signature, which in turn means we are **overloading** the method and not **overriding** it.

*The fact that you happen to call it with something that would fit into both is irrelevant, as selecting which **overloaded** method to call happens at compile time in Java, based on the variable `a2`'s type (`A`) and not the runtime class of the object it points to (`B`).*

This sort of mistake can easily happen by accident, particularly if you shuffle your methods around and rename them. To avoid accidental overloading when you meant overriding, make sure you always use the `@Override` annotation when you intend to override something, that way the compiler will complain.

```
class B extends A {
  @Override //this will compile fine
  public void dosomething1(A a){ 
    System.out.println("Inside b dosomething1");
  }

  @Override //this will fail compilation
  public void dosomething2(B b){
    System.out.println("Inside b  dosomething2");
  }
}
```

This annotation is technically optional but it is so useful that in practice people treat it as if it were mandatory.

Comment: `@Override` is only mandatory if you don't want bugs. If you don't mind bugs, you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

It is method Overriding

> Why java not calling the method defined in B as on runtime it knows a2
>   is object of B.

Because `dosomething2` in `A` and `dosomething2` in `B` have different signatures. 
You are not overriding `dosomething2` in `B`. In regard to dynamic dispatch, `dosomething2` in `B` is a new method.